# How to manage file descriptors of a process on Linux?

Tags: bash, redirection, sandbox

I have an executable file, which is a *black box* for me. now I want to execute it in a protected mode that:

1. Does not change any file on my system.
2. Does not send any information to any other place.

So I need a wrapper that logs/manages file descriptors opened by this executable file.

Take a look at [`proxychains`](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) (`apt-get install proxychains` on debian) or `torify`, they do something like that on application network connections (`proxychains firefox` would execute FireFox, while all external connections are managed by `proxychains`).

Comment: It's still way too broad. What processes are these? Please tell us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: This comment should be your question from the very beginning. Edit it once again and I'll vote to reopen it.